# Conversion of NWD (FBX) to SVF - Textures not found in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We recently discovered an issue for conversion of NWD files (with FBX) to SVF. It used to work perfectly prior to April. We still reference the same Forge libraries that we did when it worked.

The issue is that the converted SVF file does not show textures on model elements because our viewer is asking for texture files named

```
"navis_example_file_svf_tex_mod.jpg"
```

while the corresponding resource we downloaded from our bucket is

```
"navis_example_file.jpg"
```

We have asserted that the model manifest contains "navis_example_file.jpg" without the "_svf_tex_mod" suffix.

However we found a reference to "navis_example_file_svf_tex_mod.jpg" inside **Materials.json** associated with the model. Our workaround to make the model show textures is to change the reference in Materials.json to match the jpg file.

Are there any changes in the APIs for uploading/converting/downloading SVF models that could cause this issue?

**Server-side environment:** Autodesk.Forge 1.9.0 (Nuget)

We are using EMEA region for the whole process, using these endpoints:

- BucketsApi (GetBucketDetailsAsync, CreateBucketAsync, GetBucketsAsync)
- DerivativesApi (GetManifestAsync, TranslateAsync)
- ObjectsApi (UploadObjectAsync, UploadChunkAsync)

**Client-side environment:** Forge viewer (7.40).

- Initializing the viewer:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.InitializerOptions =

{ env: 'Local', useADP: false, useConsolidation: true, useCredentials: true }
```

Loading the model:

`this.viewer.loadModel("svf urn from our own server")`

**Update**

We tried to load the model directly from the Autodesk server and it works, contrary to our offline version with downloaded derivatives. We used these the settings below. The textures all have the "svf_tex_mod" suffix in this case.

```
const AUTODESK_ENVIRONMENT_OPTIONS: Autodesk.Viewing.InitializerOptions = {
  env: 'AutodeskProduction',
  accessToken: "<Access token here>",
};

...

Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:<URN here>', successCallback, ...);
```

Comment: I do not seem to hear a change with texture file name recently. Please bear with me checking with engineer team.

Comment: Thanks! Have you heard anything, @XiaodongLiang?

Comment: I did got some information, which directed me to contact other team to confirm if the change is true or it is an issue. I am trying best to get back to you as soon as possible. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Hi torjuss, the engineer team is wondering if this problem happens with online loading or it only happens after you downloaded SVF package and loaded it offline.  And could you share a urn for us to check at backend? you can email to forge.help with private data.

Comment: Hi, we create a transient bucket and download the derivatives for the model from that bucket. We refer to the manifest to find out which derivatives to download. I can try to upload the model to a persistent bucket and get back to you with a urn then. Thanks!

Comment: transient bucket only means the source objects will be deleted after 24 hours. While the corresponding derivatives will not be deleted until you explicitly request to delete (by the endpoint DELETE:derivatives ).  If the job was posted with zip (source model + texture files), you could load it online to see what would happen, without creating a new one.

Comment: In another word, if zip, after translating, the textures mapping  (no matter the file name is changed or not) is available. The customer does not need to take care of the name. If it works well online, but not works offline (after downloading the derivatives ), we will check it further

Comment: Mail sent with urn. The issue happens when loading the model "offline" (with downloaded derivatives). In the meantime I'll give online loading a try, to check if there is any difference.

Comment: Added "Update" section to the post. Loading the model online works.